# How to use add-to-list on a list returned by function

Tags: list, elisp

I have a function that return a list. It may return a blank list or a number list. I would like to apply `add-to-list` to the return value. Is it possible?

```
     (defun return-list () body....)
     (setq test (add-to-list (return-list) 1) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function [`add-to-list`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html) operates on *variables*, not *lists*.
E.g.:

```
(defvar test (return-list))
(add-to-list 'test 1)
```

If you are adding to a list *unconditionally*, use macro [`push`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html) which operates on places:

```
(push 1 test)
```

In your case, however, you can do even simpler:

```
(setq test (cons 1 (return-list)))
```

If you want to add an element only if it is not there yet, use the macro [`cl-pushnew`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Modify-Macros.html) which operates on places too:

```
(pushnew 1 test)
;; `test' is now (1)
(pushnew 1 test)
;; `test' is still (1)
```

Comment: Indeed, tho we recommend to use `cl-pushnew` (from `cl-lib`) rather than `pushnew` (from the older `cl` library).  But the main point is indeed that `add-to-list` is only intended for use when operating on things like customzation variables.